# Why my displacement looks like this?

Tags: displacement, bump

I connect the displacement node to noise texture node, and following the setup given by Blender Guru in his video, and i also make my displacement setting from bump only to displacement and bump, but the end result looks like this[image]

I dont know why my donut bump looks like this, while i aiming to make my donut like this[image]

can i still fix this? if there is something that i miss, please tell me guys... thanks

Fyi this is my file :

https://pasteall.org/blend/74781658bffd45079e624200f8687db6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have accidently duplicated the mesh and the overlap is causing the shading issues.

Steps to fix:

1. Select an element of the overlapping object.
2. Select linked (`Ctrl L`)
3. Delete all verts. (`X`)

Also note: You need more mesh resolution to display high frequency displacement add a subdivision surface modifier and increase subdivision levels as needed to fix this.

[Click here for a video of me fixing your issue.](https://i.imgur.com/uzPnX80.mp4)

[image: Picture illustrating duplicated mesh.]

Comment: Hall what do you mean by “ shading issue? " Is it about displacement problem?

Comment: By "shading issue" I am referring to the dark spots that result from the displacement.

Comment: [Click here for a video of me fixing your issue.](https://i.imgur.com/uzPnX80.mp4)

Comment: I used the exact same version as you (`2.79.7`) in my video.

Comment: How do you select the duplicated mesh without selecting the original one?

Comment: Cause when when i use select linked, all mesh are selected even though i just want select the duplicated one

Comment: Oh i have found how to do it, and it worked just like your result

Comment: @EarvinWilliams: if it helped you, you should click on the checkmark left to his answer to accept his answer

Comment: @Chris it's done

Comment: what's that for by the way?

Comment: first it is for other people to know "this is the right answer" so they don't waste time and get quick result instead of reading all the answers. second it is a way to say "thank you" for helping and so the one who answers gets some reputation points and in the long run more "power" and possibilities here (like writing comments, down and upvoting, statistics etc)

Comment: @Chris oh ok... And thanks for all of your help